# Does anyone know why my XMAPP mysql server wont connect to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am still new to mysql so Im not to sure what im doing wrong in the set up. I downloaded mysql from the website, the community server as well as work bench and it runs properly on port 3306, but when i try to connect the XMAPP server to it, it wont start. Im on a mac. Does anyone know of any problems that could be causing this. Thank you.

I tired restarting the mysql server and reconnecting it, reinstalling XMAPP, and configuring on a different port with no success yet

Comment: As first dumb question (!), did Apache server start normally ?

Comment: 'xampp dont connect to mysql' is useless for anyone here to help you... tell us how you know, what you see, what your expectation is, if some code is involved, show it,  if some logs are available, put them in your question, etc...

Comment: Is it XMAPP  or XAMPP? Because the latter is a bundle that already contains MySQL Server. If you've also installed the official package, you'll have two potentially conflicting installations. And it's also unclear what kind of connection you expect to happen between the two.